# Fortran Interoperability of long C integers

Tags: c, fortran, interop, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a C library that declares several `long` variables in structs. I usually treat them as `integer(kind=c_long)` in Fortran, but that caused unexpected issues in a specific more complex program. My Fortran code ran correctly in a 32-bit system, and didn't even compile in a 64-bit system. The reason is too complicated to explain here and it doesn't really matter for the purpose of the question, but it comes down to the fact `c_long` is not the same in 32- and 64-bit systems. At least in gfortran, `c_long` is 4 bytes in 32-bit and 8 bytes in 64-bit. In fact, `c_long = c_int = 4` in 32-bit, while in 64-bit it is `c_long = c_double = 8`.

Now, in this particular C library `long` integers are just used for `char` variables, and the maximum one used is $FFFFFF, well beyond the limit of `c_long` integers in 32-bit systems, since `huge(1_c_long)=$7FFFFFFF` in 32-bit. So I have several ways to get rid of the problem, but I still wonder... why it *has* to be that way in the first place? For example, `c_double` is the same both in 32- and 64-bit systems (as it should); same for `c_int`, it is the same no matter what. Why `c_long` is different? It took me several hours to figure out what's going on in a complex program just because of this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal length of `long` (or even of `int`). Various systems and compilers use one of the common data models ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)), which use either 32 bits and 64 bits for `int`, `long`, `long long` and pointers.

Fortran specifies the `iso_c_binding` types using the concept of a **companion processor**. That means that the Fortran compiler in its specific configuration (in a specific operating system) use the types to be compatible with a specific C compiler with some specific configuration on a specific operating system.

Notably, Microsoft and MinGW C compilers on Microsoft Windows use the LLP64 model. Compilers on Linux and other Unixes normally use the LP64 data model. Hence the size of `long` differs.

It is hard to say anything more for your situation without specific details (compilers, OS). But the sizes are not universal and only valid for a specific compiler on a specific OS that the Fortran compiler regards as the *companion processor*.

Comment: I think it is also relevant to mention the sentence: `There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.` see e.g. the paragraph "Fundamental Types" in the Cpp standard.

Comment: For those searching for some useful links to the Cpp standards: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links

Comment: This is essentially against the standard that Fortran committees tried to accomplish with stuff like `selected_int_kind` - one type is supposed to mean the exact same thing everywhere. I think in this case, the difference in `c_long` comes from the fact `long` integers differ in 32-bit C and 64-bit C, so inevitably the corresponding `c_long` types differ as well. It looks more like a problem inherited to Fortran by C (via interoperability). For the story, the above were observed with gfrortran 11.2 in GNU/Linux 32- and 64-bit systems. I rarely need/use MinGW, TDM-GCC.

Comment: The reason has little to do with the Fortran standard itself and nothing to do with stuff like `selected_int_kind` or fixed storage size kinds. The C-interoperability part of Fortran just copies C as closely as possible. If different C processors (compiler+OS) differ, Fortran compilers must be free to differ as well.

Comment: Really, you asked a general question so only a general answer is possible. You could, of course, also open a specific question with your specific details and ask for an explanation but you wrote that you do not want to do that.

Comment: @Vladimir F: Can you name a specific compiler+OS combination where even `int` is different? At least in gfortran `c_int`, `c_double` mean the exact same thing no matter if it is a 32-bit or a 64-bit GCC implementation.

Comment: @Pap In the ILP64 data model the `int` has 64 bits, in the SILP64 data model even `short` has 64 bits. Please see the Wikipedia page for the details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: Of course it has nothing to do with the Fortran standard. I just said the problem comes from C via interoperability *and* that goes against what the Fortran standard tried to accomplish. It is not a Fortran problem, it seems. It's all about C - again.

Comment: @Pap `double` can also be anything. Please remember that not all CPUs follow IEEE 754. Of course, all modern ones do, but C and Fortran have existed for decades and allow the older CPU architectures.  It is also allowed to promote float to 64-bit and double to 128-bit even if rarely done. In Fortran these promotions are more common because the system API is not in Fortran but in C.

Answer (score 0):

The following small program reveals what's going on:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf(" Maximum int: %X (%u bytes)\n",INT_MAX,sizeof(int));
  printf("Maximum long: %lX (%u bytes)\n",LONG_MAX,sizeof(long));
  return 0;
}
```

With gcc 11.2 on a 32-bit GNU/Linux system this gives:

```
 Maximum int: 7FFFFFFF (4 bytes)
Maximum long: 7FFFFFFF (4 bytes)
```

And on a 64-bit system it gives:

```
 Maximum int: 7FFFFFFF (4 bytes)
Maximum long: 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (8 bytes)
```

Therefore, Fortran did nothing wrong. The problem (or however one might want to call it) comes from the C side. There is no standard - or at least not *one* standard - and C doesn't have something similar to Fortran's fixed-size kinds (which isn't perfect, but at least makes things somewhat less confusing). `long` integers are just different in C, depending on your operating system. So `iso_c_binding` had no choice but to provide different `c_long` types as well.

Lesson learned: Never ever *assume* anything. There ain't such a thing as a single, universal `c_long` and, as Vladimir F pointed out, there ain't such a thing as a single universal `c_int` (or whatever else) either.

Comment: C does also have fixed size numeric types. Include `stdint.h` and use `int32_t`, `int64_t` or `int128_t`. It is up to you, how you design your software, you can use the traditional types, that are available everywhere, or the fixed types that are not guaranteed to exist (some old CPUs or even older non-CPU computers may not support them and use other word sizes). For Fortran interoperability one then uses `c_int32_t`, `c_int64_t` and `c_int128_t`.

Comment: And Fortran is really not very different from C here.  All the details of specific Fortran `kind` numbers are implementation-specific: which ones are valid for which types, what their specific significance is, which one is the default for each type.  What Fortran can boast here is that it has a better-developed system for choosing specific data types based on their properties.

Comment: @VladimirF I am aware of `stdint.h`, but most of the time the reason I bother with C is just for interoperability with a C library. - and none of them uses `stdint.h` but rather the "traditional" types. Even in the most recent libraries, heavily developed today, `int32_t` etc is a very rare sight, so practically useless, at least for my needs.
@JohnBollinger That is why I said Fortran's fixed-size numeric types aren't perfect.